# How do you append a class object to a list in Python

Tags: python, list

Im attempting to append a class object to a list, the class being from a different file

heres the source code from main.py:

```
environmentVector = []
environment.environment1 = environment.environment(100, 100, 32, 32)
environmentVector.append(environment.environment1)
```

and heres the class from environment.py:

```
class environment():
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.x1 = x - 16
    self.x2 = x + 16
    self.y1 = y - 16
    self.y2 = y + 16
```

this code throws an error saying

```
AttributeError: module 'environment' has no attribute 'environmentVector'
```

Comment: You're never instantiating your class: `environmentVector.append(environment(5, 2, 1, 3))`

Comment: What do you mean by class object? Do you mean an instance of the class, or the class itself? Usually, "class object" means the class itself in python.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 that's going to raise something about module objects not being callable. The OP has neglected to say that they are importing a module with the same name as the class into in their `main.py` module, I suspect because they are coming from Java

Comment: The error has nothing to do with appending to a list. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Is your `environment` class in a file name `environment.py`?  If you just do `import environment`, then the `environment` object in your importing code will be a module, not the class.

Comment: @AdamSmith then why are they getting `AttributeError: module 'environment' has no attribute 'x1'`?

Comment: @AdamSmith all of this ambiguity could be resolved, of course, if the op provides a [mcve]

Comment: updated the code so the class is instantiated and now it throws a different error code is updated

Comment: the environmentVector list isnt in the module environment does it need to be or how can this code be fixed

Comment: @agtv look at your code carefully. I think you've typo'd something that hasn't been copied here.

Comment: @agtv similarly, you probably don't need `environment1` to live in the `environment` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two problems. First of all when you do:

```
import environment
```

that sets `environment` to the namespace that *contains* your `environment` class, not to the class itself. This is different from some other OOP languages (Java, for instance).

```
# My sample environment.py
class Environment(object):
    pass

foo = "bar"
```

```
# my sample main.py
import environment

# environment.Environment is the class
# environment.Environment() is an instance of that class.
# environment.foo is "bar"
```

The first problem is that you're using `environment` where you should use `environment.environment`. The *second* problem is that you're using `environment` when you should ***actually*** be using `environment.environment(some_x, some_y, some_width, some_height)`. You need to instantiate your class before trying to use it as an instance!